# MySQL Collation utf8_unicode differences

Tags: mysql

But I've been reading up on the importance of MySQL Collation and what I have learned so far regarding compatibility and accuracy is these 4 seem to be my best bet.

- utf8_unicode_ci
- utf8_unicode_520_ci
- utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

From my understanding uft8mb4 would be good for character with mutli language (character) support (japanese for example). uf8 only supports 3 bytes while uf8mb4 supports 4 bytes. So it sounds like the obvious choice would be uf8mb4, but the catch seems to be that you have a length limit (Damn it! I want my cake and eat it too), which is a little concern (I think).

Then you take into account about the 520 standard; which offers more, from what little I could find on it. But that is of course the issue, I could find very little about it. Only that people say it's an improvement, yet being very vague on how that is.

I do want the most I can get with as few restrictions as possible... I figured someone here may know a thing or two. The official MySQL site wasn't as informative as I had hoped it was.

Of the 4 which would offer the most compatibility, accuracy, and the most storage length? Also what truly is the big difference between the 502 standard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unicode collation names may include a version number to indicate the version of the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) on which the collation is based. UCA-based collations without a version number in the name use [the `version-4.0.0` UCA weight keys](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/4.0.0/allkeys-4.0.0.txt). A collation name such as `utf8_unicode_520_ci` is based on [UCA 5.2.0 weight keys](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/5.2.0/allkeys.txt).

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-names.html.

Comment: To further explain on this: the collation will not modify the encoding used (what MySQL wrongly calls `character set` or `charset`), so `utf8` will provide you 3-byte (non-standard) UTF-8 and `utf8mb4` will provide you 4-byte UTF-8.

Comment: So in simple English what is the difference between UCA 4.0.0 and UCA 5.2.0 other than one is newer. What would the advantage or disadvantage be?

Comment: It affects sorting. If you absolutely need to sort against a more recent (but still outdated) version of the Unicode standard, then you may want to use `520_ci`. For my websites I couldn’t care less.

Comment: what is the byte size of the largest byte size character in the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` collation?

Comment: @oldboy: Four bytes. As a collation, it's a change in sort-related mechanisms, not size.

Comment: @GreenReaper thanks