# Wrong sort order using utf8_unicode_ci and swedish characters like ö

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, collation, character-set, encoding

I am confused about what encoding and collation I should use so my queries returns the correct sort order.

Right now my encoding is `UTF-8 Unicode` and collation `utf8_unicode_ci` for both `firstname` and `lastname`.

And the sort order would be something like this:

```
firstname  lastname
aaa        aaa
ööö        ööö
ooo        ooo
ppp        ppp
qqq        qqq
```

`ööö ööö` should be after `qqq qqq`

Changing collation to `utf8_swedish_ci` works correctly:

```
firstname  lastname
aaa        aaa
ooo        ooo
ppp        ppp
qqq        qqq
ööö        ööö
```

But `utf8_unicode_520_ci` give me the same result as `utf8_unicode_ci`, shouldn't it work too?

The funny part is if I only change `firstname` collation to `utf8_unicode_520_ci` it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, someone addressed this apparent difference.

Matthias Bynens answered the post [MySQL Collation utf8_unicode differences](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65863/mysql-collation-utf8-unicode-differences/76976#76976) abour 4 years ago.

He mentioned "Weight Keys"

- [version-4.0.0 UCA weight keys](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/4.0.0/allkeys-4.0.0.txt)
- utf8_unicode_520_ci is based on [UCA 5.2.0 weight keys](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/5.2.0/allkeys.txt)

For more information, go to [The Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/).

Comment: I did see that post, but didn't understand how it related to my problem. Now I can see how the weight keys decides the sort order for the different collations.

Answer (score 1):

Where does Ö sort?

- utf8_estonian_ci: Between 'W' and 'X'
- danish, icelandic, swedish: After 'Z'
- utf8_gernan2_ci: As if the two letters 'oe'
- hungarian and turkish: Between 'O' and 'P' (that is, after 'oz')
- Other collations (including unicode, unicode_520, 0900): As if the letter 'O'

These apply to both utf8 and utf8mb4, MySQL 8.0 and before.

[*Programatically generated collation tester*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html)

Danish, icelandic, or swedish will work 'correctly' for 'Ö'.  Here are the differences among those three:

In icelandic, `AZ < Á < B,  E < É,  IZ < Í < J,  UZ < Ü < V,  YZ < Ý < Z`.  Also

```
danish:    zz <          Ä=Æ=ä=æ < Ö=Ø=ö=ø < Aa=Å=å < Þ=þ
icelandic: zz < Þ=þ    < Ä=Æ=ä=æ < Ö=Ø=ö=ø <    Å=å
swedish:   zz <    Å=å < Ä=Æ=ä=æ < Ö=Ø=ö=ø <          Þ=þ
```

(This may not have all the differences.)